# A record with contradicting NS record

Tags: domain-name-system, domains

The a record is to map an ip with a domain right?

But what if you set the a record to a specific ip and you set the nameservers too
and the nameservers return an ip that is different that the ip specified in the a record?

Or is it so that the one overrides the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nameserver associated with a domain tells the Internet who to ask for the A records for that domain, so the chain may go Domain Name -> Nameserver -> A record -> IP address (the nameserver is looked up first and has a different role to the A record).